# domain modeling the service of the priest in the temple

Tags: f#

I am attempting to practice my domain modeling, by attempting to model [this](https://www.chabad.org/dailystudy/rambam.asp?tdate=1/15/2019&rambamChapters=1) event.

> The wine and the fine flour that are brought together with an
>   offering are called accompanying offerings. The fine flour alone is
>   called the accompanying meal-offering. The accompanying meal-offering
>   need not be waved, brought [to the corner of the altar], nor [offered
>   with] frankincense. It requires salt and it is burnt on the outer
>   altar in its entirety.
>
> The wine is poured over the altar. It is not poured over the fire.
>   Instead, the priest should lift up his hands and pour it on [the
>   altar's] base and from there, it descends to the shittin.

I've attempted to simplify by expressing the record types that we are dealing with:

```
type AlterLocations = 
    | Outer
    | Corner
    | Base

type AccompanyingOfferings = 
    | Wine
    | Flour

type AccompanyingMealOfferings = 
    | FineFlour

type Auxilary = 
    | Salt
    | Frankinsense

type Offering =
    {
        Name: string
    }
```

However, I am getting stuck on modeling the actual *event*:

```
type MealOffering = 
    {
        Offering:Offering
        Flour:AccompanyingMealOfferings
        Waved: bool
        RequiresSalt: bool
        OfferedWithFrankinse: bool
        ShouldBeBroughtToCorner: bool
        EntirelyBurnt: bool
    }
```

**How can we represent a type that might have multiple tags/flags?**

Comment: What do you mean by "tags/flags"?

Comment: I assume that means there could be more than one `AccompanyingOfferings` at the same time, for example. That could be modeled with a list (which has the downside of allowing several entries of the same "kind", like `[ Wine; Wine ]`) or, .NET specific, with a `Flags` enum: `[<Flags>] type AccompanyingOfferings = | None = 0 | Wine = 1 | Flour = 2` (the next one would have to be 4, then 8, because they're flags in a bit mask).

Comment: @TeaDrivenDev that's exactly what i meant, though i'm not sure i would like that solution, i am wondering if there is a more f# primitive way to describe it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take a page from how [Argu](http://fsprojects.github.io/Argu/) handles command-line arguments and do something like this:

```
type OfferingFlags =
    | Waved
    | RequiresSalt
    | OfferedWithFrankincense
    | ShouldBeBroughtToCorner
    | EntirelyBurnt
```

Then the `MealOffering` type might look like this:

```
type MealOffering = 
    {
        Offering: Offering
        Flour: AccompanyingMealOfferings
        Flags: OfferingFlags list
    }
```

A flag *not* present in the list represents a `false` value, and a flag present in the list represents a `true` value for that flag. I.e., to check whether an offering requires salt, you'd do:

```
offering.Flags |> List.contains RequiresSalt
```

And the list for an accompanying meal-offering (which requires salt, is entirely burnt, but does *not* need to be waved, brought to the corner, or be offered with frankincense), would look like:

```
[ RequiresSalt; EntirelyBurnt ]
```

The advantage of this modeling method is that no matter how many flags you have, you can add a new flag without having to edit the `MealOffering` type. This can also be a disadvantage, because when you model each flag separately as a `bool`, any time you add a new flag the compiler forces you to consider it everywhere -- whereas by modeling it as a list of DU values, the compiler won't force you to check the new `RequiresSomethingElse` flag in the places where it needs to be done. BUT if you think you're done adding new flags, or if any new flag you add should also default to `false` in most places, then the `OfferingFlags list` approach is generally a good one.